# Number of zeros equal number of linearly independent analytic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, vector-spaces, roots, residue-calculus

I'm trying to read [this paper](http://prb.aps.org/abstract/PRB/v31/i4/p2529_1) and I'm stuck on a particular point. The authors are constructing an analytic function $f(z)$ which have to satisfy the following boundary conditions:

$\frac{f(z+L_1)}{f(z)}=e^{i\phi_1}\ \ $ and $\ \ \frac{f(z+L_2e^{i\theta})}{f(z)}e^{i\pi N_s\big(2z+L_2e^{i\theta}\big)/L_1}=e^{i\phi_2}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ $ (1)

where $z=x+iy$, $N_s\in \boldsymbol{N}$, $\theta\in[0,\pi/2]$ and $L_1,L_2\in \boldsymbol{R}_+$.

Using the residue theorem they argue that this means $f(z)$ has $N_s$ zeros in the parallelogram defined by $\boldsymbol{L}_1=(L_1,0)$ and $\boldsymbol{L}_2=(L_2\cos\theta,L_2\sin\theta)$.

Then comes my problem: The authors write that this implies (1) has $N_s$ linearly independent solutions. I don't understand why exactly; is this a general theorem about numbers of zeros and linearly independent functions?

EDIT: I've thought of the following approach, with one especially uncertain point:

Since $f(z)$ is analytic it converges to its Taylor series. Having $N_s$ roots it can be written as a polynomial of degree $N_s$ (this is where I'm the most unsure, especially with $\sin(z)$ etc in mind). Thinking of the function space as a vector space with basis $B=\{1,z,z^2,\ldots\}$ this means that there are exactly $N_s$ linearly independent functions with this number of roots.

Can anyone see a flaw in this argument? Or a way to strengthen it?

Answer (score 1):

These are not actually “boundary” conditions. These conditions define a linear bundle over an [elliptic curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve#Elliptic_curves_over_the_complex_numbers) (torus).

Authors apparently refer to the [Riemann–Roch theorem for an elliptic curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Roch_theorem#Genus_one). I don’t understand this stuff very well, but this theorem relates the dimension of the space of holomorphic sections of a linear bundle (≈ functions with “conditions”) over complex curves with a topological invariant of the bundle known as the “degree”, “Euler number”, or “Chern number $c_1$” (see also [this Mathoverflow thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/70797/complex-line-bundle-over-curves)).

BTW, fractional Hall effect requires very elaborate mathematics.